# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tcp, tomcat7, connection-reset

I am encountering this following exception on our production setup. Below is the trace,

**Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset**

```
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:532)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer$InputStreamInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:563)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:124)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:346)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:200)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Channels.java:385)
```

Below are the configuration details for tomcat.

1. Connector - BIO
2. Max threads - 100
3. Accept Count - 20000

Most common case i have come across the web is the client closing out on the connection before the server responds back. However this does not seem to be the case here.
I just want to try to understand why this is happening. Have been try to reproduce this at my end without much luck.

Couple of things already tried,

1. Set a break point in the server code, hit from the client, waited for a min (> 20000) and then ran it to completion. No error here.
2. Set a break point in the server code. Hit from the client code, it stopped at the server break point, then i stopped/closed the client and let the server code run to completion, this too didn't result in any errors.

Any ideas on how do i reproduce this problem at my end locally.

Thanks,

Vicky

Comment: are the clients (in respect to the server) behind firewalls , switches, routers etc?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy - The one i am trying to reproduce locally, both client and server at localhost. However on production, the application is load balanced and gets hits from external clients.

Comment: Im having the same problem and i think whatever is in front of tomcat(load balancer etc) is dropping some of the excessive connections under heavy load(higher than it can handle). Were you able to identify the cause?

Comment: Hi .. I am facing the same issue in our application during heavy load on production .. Any imputs will be much appreciated .. thanks. @Vicky